# Flutter Navigator route always "/"

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, stack-navigator

I'm using custom `Navigator` widget and wrap it using `WillPopScope` to handle routing in my app.
But I encounter problems with getting which exact route is on top of the stack when popping or pushing. I need to detect these changes to always display current route name in the appbar.

I'm using `ModalRoute.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).settings.name` for that, but the route printed is always "/", even though switching pages and popping them using back buttons works perfectly.

inside my `main.dart`'s Scaffold:

```
WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          if (navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {

            //trying to catch name of the route during pop. results always "/"
            print(ModalRoute.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).settings.name);

            navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: Navigator(
          key: navigatorKey,
          initialRoute: '/',
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {

            //Each route(page) has one big button on it which leads to the next route
            //(BTW, stack is simple, linear, ProductChoice -> ShapeChoice -> ShapeEditor -> More
            // and reverse is the only possible way to navigate, for max simplicity)

            Map<String, Widget> pages = {
              "/": ProductChoice(
                navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                swipeDownCallback: () {},
              ),
              "/shapeChoice": ShapeChoice(
                navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                swipeDownCallback: () {},
              ),
              "/shapeEditor": ShapeEditor(
                navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                shapeName: glassDataState.current["dimensions"]["shapeName"],
                swipeDownCallback: () {},
              ),
              "/more": More(),
            };
            
            //Could it be pageTransition's fault? Animations seem to work fine
            return pageTransition(pages[settings.name], Offset(1, 0));
          },
        ),
      ),
```

I pass navigatorKey to routes so that each button on each route can do this(Eg: `ProductChoice`):

```
return BigButton(
            title: title,
            onClick: () {
              navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed("/shapeChoice");
```

There is also 2nd button on each page, its used to go back:

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
```

It's that simple, but `ModalRoute.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).settings.name` returns "/" everywhere.

I've also tried: `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name`, same results.

Not sure if `pageTransition` could matter, but anyways:

```
Route pageTransition(Widget toPage, Offset begin) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => toPage,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      // var begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      var end = Offset.zero;
      var curve = Curves.fastOutSlowIn;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I resolved this issue using custom simple stack implementation.

In my case, it was just a matter of:

```
  navigateBack() {
    if (currentSlide >= 2) {
      updateIndex(1);
    } else if (currentSlide == 1) {
      updateIndex(0);
    } else if (currentSlide == -1) {
      updateIndex(prevSlide);
    }
  }
```

Stack of 2 pages (`currentSlide`, `prevSlide`) was enough for me. Shouldn't be too hard to implement a little more complex stack using an array.

I also put it in a state object which tracks currently open page. To capture the back button and stop it from popping the route automatically, I return "false" inside `onWillPop`, and then handle everything myself:

```
WillPopScope(
        // onWillPop: () async {
        //   if (navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {
        //     print(ModalRoute.of(navigatorKey.currentContext).settings.name);
        //     navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
        //     return false;
        //   }
        //   return true;
        // },
        onWillPop: () async {
          if (navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {

            //use custom state that tracks everything itself instead
            appBarState.navigateBack(); 

            //but also keep using navigator for popping and animation transitions
            navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
          }
          return false;
        },
```

Since I also have other ways of navigating across the app, like buttons, I need to use my custom `appBarState.navigateBack()` implementation there too:

```
 child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // Navigator.of(pContext).pop();
            if (appBarState.currentSlide != 0) {
              appBarState.navigateBack(); 
              widget.navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
```

Also implemented a way for updating stack when we are moving "forwards". `navigateForwards()`. Call it everywhere where I call `navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed("/route")`

Ideally I could also move `navigatorKey` into the state so that I wouldn't have to duplicately call pop & custom `appBarState.navigateBack()`.

That workaround/solution also gives me more control over how exactly I want my navigator to behave. Since its modifying my global state too(Your exact State implementation doesn't really matter, but I'm using a combination of `getIt` and `rxdart`), now I can catch any changes in my navigation on any page I want and anytime.

Hope I could help somebody too. Keep it simple.